# Loop through Multidimensional (nested) Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like below and would like to create a `<html>` form out of it. I tried to accomplish that but I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the inner/nested array, that have the values that i want to use.

Can anyone help me out? Just to be clear, I would like a html output like:

```
<form method="get">
    <h2>I have</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" value="own studio">own studio<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="mobile studio">mobile studio<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="makeup artist">makeup artist<br>
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <select>
        <option value="Private">Private</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Function**

```
<?php
function get_listing_cfs() {
global $wpdb; 
$serialized=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='va_form'"); 
$array=unserialize($serialized);
$source = array_filter($array, function($el) {
    return !(
            $el['props']['label'] == 'Exclude' ||
            $el['props']['label'] == 'Exclude 2'
            );
});
//echo '<pre>'.print_r($source, true).'</pre>';
$toreturn = '<form method="get">';
    foreach ($source as $key => $item) {
    $toreturn .= '<h2>'.$source[$key]['props']['label'].'</h2>';
        if ($source[$key]['type'] == 'select'){
        $toreturn .= '<select>';
        // Scan through inner loop
            foreach ($item as $value =>$data) {
               $toreturn .='<option value="'.$value['props']['options'].'">'.$value['props']['options'].'</option>';
            }
        $toreturn .='</select>';    
        }
        if ($source[$key]['type'] == 'checkbox'){
        // Scan through inner loop
            foreach ($item as $value =>$data) {
               $toreturn .='<input type="checkbox" value="'.$value['props']['options'].'">'.$value['props']['options'].'<br />';
            }
        }
    }
    $toreturn .= '</form>';
return $toreturn;
}
?>
```

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => app_i_have
            [type] => checkbox
            [props] => Array
                (
                    [required] => 0
                    [label] => I have
                    [tip] => 
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [baseline] => 0
                                    [value] => mobile studio
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [baseline] => 0
                                    [value] => own studio
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [baseline] => 0
                                    [value] => makeup artist
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => app_customers
            [type] => select
            [props] => Array
                (
                    [required] => 0
                    [label] => Customers
                    [tip] => 
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [baseline] => 0
                                    [value] => Private
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [baseline] => 0
                                    [value] => Business
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Besides not making good use of your loop variables, you've got nested looping. Whats not working?

Comment: Hi, I am not very known with arrays. The problem is with the nested arrays. I am trying to get the [value] from the array(where it says '// Scan through inner loop'), but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're not considering your data structure at all.

```
foreach ($item as $value =>$data) {
    $toreturn .='<option value="'.$value['props']['options'].'">'.$value['props']['options'].'</option>';
}
```

In this, `$item` is

```
[props] => Array
    (
        [required] => 0
        [label] => I have
        [tip] => 
        [options] => Array
```

So looping through it would be looping through the properties, not the values. You want to loop `$item['options']`.

Over all, if you're not experienced with array (a base and necessary type in PHP), I suggest you go back and do some starter material before trying something like this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a bit, but i still don't know how to loop through the nested arrays and it is not really up to me to go back. This is the array i get from the database. Quite figured out how to return the array data that i want, but the nested array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I put the stuff you need to loop through above. You need to loop through the array of options you want to display, not just the group. The structure you're getting back from the database is fine; you just need to actually loop through the values you want. If you're not following why you need to loop through `$items['options']`, I'd say you really need to go back and learn the basics first.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes i do know why i should loop through the $item[options] but i don't understand why. The amount of options differ per array..How can i get the different option values?

Comment: Why should you loop through options? Because you're trying to display the options... What does the number of options matter? You're looping. You're telling me you know why you should loop through options and asking me how you can get the different options at the same time.

Comment: Different options as in different values (options for the form).

Comment: I guess I don't know what you're asking then. The `options` subarray contains the options for the input, thus you need to loop through it to get individual values to display. It really sounds like you don't understand how arrays work, and if so, SO is not the place to answer that; you need to do a basic review on arrays and looping. You're already looping through your different inputs. Within each input, you need to loop through the individual options. I can't simply it further.

Comment: Ok.. i can't seem to figure out how to loop through the individual options, but i will seek further.. thanks for your time.

Comment: Except I told you how to loop through individual options: you want to loop through `$items['options']`. It's the array containing your options. Look at your data structure and your variables (which are all over the place and being used interchangably, which is probably part of why you're confused). What does `$item` contain? What does `$item['options']` contain?

Comment: I tried `foreach ($item['options'] as $value =>$data)` and then use `$value['value']` for the value, but that is not giving me a result.

Comment: Why would it? `$value` is your key. It's very obvious you don't understand how foreach loops work, given how you're using your variables. Go figure them out and it should become clear.